# The distance between 2 planes on a cube

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry

Given cube $PQRS-TUVW$. It has the length of the side is $3\sqrt3 cm$. What is the distance between $PRW$ plane and $QVT$ plane?

Attempt:

Cz there's no information about the labelling, i consider $PQRS$ is a clockwise direction of the cube's label and $TUVW$ as well.

The distance between $PRW$ amd $QVT$ plane is of course the same as the half of the diagonal space of the cube.

So, to find the half of the diagonal space, i use the area formula of the triangle $PQR$.

$\begin{align}
A. PQR &= A. PQR\\
\frac 12*(3\sqrt3)^2 &= \frac 12* 3 \sqrt6 * x\\
x &= \frac 32 \sqrt6
\end{align}$

And $x$ is the distance, approximately $x=3.67$. But, my friends found it $3$. Which one is true?

Btw here is my [sketch](https://ibb.co/2Nxnzxz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(PWR)||(TQV)$ and $US\perp(PWR),$ we obtain that the needed distance is $$\frac{1}{3}US=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{3(3\sqrt3)^2}=3.$$

Comment: Can you tell me where's my mistake please.

Comment: @user516076 It's not $\frac{1}{2}US$, but $\frac{1}{3}US$. Also, you made a mistake in the calculating of the diagonal. I think it's better just see my post.

Comment: @user516076 Yes, of course.

Comment: Thank you,finally i understand. So embarrassing i can't do this.

Comment: @user516076  Good luck!